# hide function parameters not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `show` function in my script. i m also passing parameters in that function, but it showing error. im using below code, while click a button i call this next() function.

```
function next() {
    $('#img1').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1400);
}
```

this is not worked for me. showing this error `Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function`. while passing without parameters it works fine.

Comment: Do you want to use animation?

Comment: I need to hide and show img while click next and another prev button accordingly, so i go with this.

Comment: @Raja  user loccai (lacking comment rep atm.) wants to know if you were able to get rid of this. Your code snippet works as expected... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({width:'toggle'}, 350);
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show/hide</button>
<br/><br/>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i want to hide left. like a slide. http://jsfiddle.net/xu3ck/16/ here it works but in my code not working.

Answer (score 1):

What about a customized animation as below:

HTML

```
<div class='div1' id="div1"></div>
<button id="showhide"></button>
```

CSS

```
.div1{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
.hide{
  width:0;  
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("showhide").addEventListener("click",function(){
   if(document.getElementById("div1").classList.contains("hide")){
        document.getElementById("div1").classList.remove("hide");
   }
   else{
        document.getElementById("div1").classList.add("hide");
   }
})
```